# Design Bug: irregular tag text alignment

Tags: bug, design

[image]

Text within the "tag pill" design element have irregular baseline alignment, possibly related to question length line-wrap.

Comment: I'm not seeing this. What browser are you on?

Comment: firefox 14, but I see it on my mobile device also (chrome) when "request desktop version" is enabled

Comment: firefox 28 (current)

Comment: I'm using FF28.0 on OSX 10.9.2 and I can't reproduce this bug.

Comment: It is visible in Alan's screenshots also: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/904/design-bug-in-ie11-on-win8-1